# Loading .dll into separate application domain (MEF)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mef

I'm trying to load an assembly into a separate applicaiton domain.
I don't want to create any instances or execute the assembly. So I'm not using **CreateInstanceAndUnwrap** method. I just want to load the dll file (not creating any types from it etc..)

```
        var cat = new AggregateCatalog();
        pluginApplicationDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("pluginApplicationDomain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
        appDomainInfo);

        cat.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(pluginApplicationDomain.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(plugin))));
```

and plugin is a relative path to the dll file.

**../../Extensions/Plugins\MyAssembly.dll**

This throws '*System.IO.FileNotFoundException*' 
The path is correct, and if I do `Assembly.LoadFrom(plugin)`, it doesn't throw any exceptions, so I'm guessing it's not the path that's incorrect.

Other solutions all used `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`, but what if the assembly and its types are black box to me? I know it impements one interface and that's it?

[Load dll into another domain exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974828/load-dll-into-another-domain-exception)

would this work? However my method's signature doesn't match that one of `CrossAppDomainDelegate`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, i mean, why do you need to load the assembly to separate domain?

Comment: Since it's a plugin, I want to have it loaded in a separate domain because if the plugin crashes, the main application won't, because it's in a different domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MEF is more about extensibility and it seems like you **actually looking for [MAF]**[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835182/choosing-between-mef-and-maf-system-addin). From my personal experience if your plugins going to invoke some native code (interact with hardware for example) AppDomains will not prevent crashes. It's safer to host such plugins in [separate processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn519924.aspx).